# Debugger has reference error for global variable when debugging inside a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, reference, global-variables

I'm trying to implement linked list in JS and I understood that js **pass by value the reference** so my code is working right but to make sure that i understand this well i tried to debug my code to see the global list and the reference passed to the function but it seems to me that the **debugger has a reference error**,can anyone tell me why and correct me if I understand this wrong regarding passing by value the reference
here's a screenshot for the debugging process and the code snippet
thanks in advance
[image: debugging my code]

```js
var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: null
  }
}

function listAdd(addedValue, mlist) {
  //var tail=list.rest;
  while (true) {
    if (mlist.rest != null) {
      mlist = mlist.rest;
    } else if (mlist.rest == null) {
      mlist.rest = {
        value: addedValue,
        rest: null
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

listAdd(3, list)
listAdd(4, list)
console.log(list)
```

Comment: The variable definition and the function are actually defined in a module, and you've imported the function, and the function calls are outside of the namespace of the module ..? When you declare a variable in a module, it won't be global, it's accessible in the namespace of the imported module only.

Comment: sorry but I'm still newbie in JS so where is this module stuff is ? and if you can provide a more information to search for it